# Defining $f(x)=mx+b$ with $m,b$ separate versus `f[m_ ,b_ ,x_]:=mx+b`

Tags: function-construction, style, parameters

Suppose I want to define a function $f(x)=mx+b$. And suppose I might want to change $m$ or $b$ later.

Specifically, suppose I initially want $m=-2,b=10$, but maybe will change these values later

Two ways I can think of to do this are

```
slope=-2;
intercept=10;
f[x_]:= intercept+slope*x
```

or, I can define it as

```
f[intercept_,slope_,x_]:=intercept+slope*x
f[10,-2,x]
```

**Does anyone have suggestions vs when to use one approach vs the other?**

I usually do a hybrid kind of thing, when I use the latter way, but then define something like `slopeCase1=-2; interceptCase1=10;` and then call `f[interceptCase1,slopeCase1,x]`, but this looks ugly is probably problematic in more ways than one.

The former way seems nicer to me, but I always worry that when I later go and change slope (say `slope=-3`), some definition somewhere will not be changed because of some technicality.

- (If I am only calling `f[x_]` once this is not really a worry, but if I use `f` in another function, which is used in another, etc, theres a lot of places where a mistake can happen

Answer (score 6):

Consider defining the function family instead of the function:

```
f[b_, m_] := Function[{x}, m x + b];
```

Then:

```
fcase1 = f[10, -2];
fcase2 = f[10, -3];

{fcase1[x], fcase2[x]}
```

Comment: Would `fcase1` and `fcase2` be "Listable", or would I need to be explicit and use something like `Function[Null, m*#+b,Listable]`?

Comment: @user106860 `fcase1` and `fcase2` are listable due to internal vectorization of `Plus` and `Times` and will be hundreds to thousands times more efficient than `Function[..., Listable]`.  If you call `fcase1` etc. on only a few thousand `x`, the difference in efficiency won't matter that much.